# Importing a model into R, that was created in a newer version of H2O

Tags: h2o

I have `H2O` version `3.22.0.1` where I have created several models using Flow.

I now want to import them into R (v 3.5.1) for further analysis.

However, the version of the package for R is `h2o_3.20.0.8` and I receive this error when running `h2o.loadModel()`

```
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 
ERROR MESSAGE:
Found version 3.22.0.1, but running version 3.20.0.8
```

I saw somewhere in the documentation that the versions must correspond, so is there a (development?) version of the R package for `H2O` which corresponds to H2O version `3.22.0.1` ? If not, is there any other work-around to import and use models built using Flow `3.22.0.1` in R (other than to revert to version `3.20.0.8` of H2O)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the R package for 3.22.0.1 from here:

- http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-xia/1/index.html

At the time of this comment, this is the latest stable release.

The version in CRAN is often a release or two behind, but you can always download the latest stable version from the H2O website.  All versions of H2O are archived in S3.  Every version is there, you just need to find the right link.

The message "Found version 3.22.0.1, but running version 3.20.0.8" means there is a mismatch between the version of the R package and a running H2O server on your host.  You might start by making sure the H2O java processes are all stopped before trying to start a new one from R.  (If you're not exactly sure how to do that, worst case just reboot your laptop.)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve any problem with H2O version mismatch try

```
h2o.shutdown()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).